# Aggregation in R with data.table instead of dplyr

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I'd like to realize the following code (made with dplyr) with data.table:

```
dataset <- dataset_raw %>%
    group_by(month, day, scoring) %>%
    summarise(count = n()) %>%
    mutate(perc = count / sum(count))
```

I have 5 possible score (ranging from 1 to 5). I succeeded to get the distribution of these scores (in percent) for each day. 
Now I just try to get the same thing with data.table. 
The 3 first lines are easy to do :

```
dataset <- dataset_raw[, .(count = .N), by = .(month, day, scoring)]
```

It gives :

```
  month   day scoring count
  <int> <int>   <int> <int>
1     4    13       1   863
2     4    13       2   450
3     4    13       3  3239
4     4    13       4   913
5     4    13       5    42
6     4    14       1   245
```

However I don't manage to do this : `perc = count / sum(count)`

Which shoud give :

```
  month   day scoring count        perc
  <int> <int>   <int> <int>       <dbl>
1     4    13       1   863 0.156709642
2     4    13       2   450 0.081714182
3     4    13       3  3239 0.588160523
4     4    13       4   913 0.165788996
5     4    13       5    42 0.007626657
6     4    14       1  2457 0.211336659
```

As you can see, `sum(count)` is supposed to be the sum of `count`s within a day, that is to say :

```
sum(score1) + sum(score2) + sum(score3) + sum(score4) + sum(score5)
```

I've try the following but it doesn't give me what I'm looking for :

```
dataset <- dataset_raw[,.(count=.N),by=.(month,day,scoring)][,.(count,pe‌​rc=count/sum(count))‌​,by=.(month,day,scor‌​ing)]
```

Return :

```
   month day scoring count perc
1:     4  13       3  3239    1
2:     4  13       1   863    1
3:     4  13       4   913    1
4:     4  13       2   450    1
5:     4  13       5    42    1
6:     4  14       4  1768    1
```

Any ideas ?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_2.2.1     dplyr_0.5.0       data.table_1.10.4
```

Comment: Your solution might be `distaggrVDRdt_day <- dataset_in[,.(count=.N),by=.(month,day,scoring)][,.(count,perc=count/sum(count)),by=.(month,day,scoring)]`

Comment: Please see point 2 in the 'top 3 mistakes' section here : https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Support#top-3-mistakes

Comment: Thanks a lot four your answers, I've edited my post.